# Android Bitmap Alpha Banding

Tags: android, bitmap, alphablending

I have a png of a radial alpha gradient, so at the edges its black and in the center is completely transparent with a nice smooth gradient.

When I load my Bitmap and display it on a SurfaceView Canvas, I get bad alpha banding. Instead of a nice smooth gradient, the alpha values seem to jump down and results in big bands of all the same alpha values.

As far as I know, bitmaps with alpha channels should not be converted when they are loaded in or drawn. How do I get my png to be drawn properly on the canvas?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! =D